# EPPlus is generating unknown file type instead of excel file ?

Tags: c#, epplus

I am using EPPlus library for creating excel file. here is the code that I am using

```
public static byte[] CreateExcelFile(DataTable dataTable)
{
    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        //Create the worksheet
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
        ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);
        //Format the header for column A1:AZ1
        using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:AZ1"])
        {
            rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        }
        ////Example how to Format Column 1 as numeric 
        //using (ExcelRange col = ws.Cells[2, 1, 2 + dataTable.Rows.Count, 1])
        //{
        //    col.Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.00";
        //    col.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right;
        //}
        return pck.GetAsByteArray();
    }
}
```

Then I am generating a resposne with this content type : "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

the file is being downloaed but with unknown type. If you rename the file to a.xlsx it will open the excel file.

I was using an old version then I updated the dll with the latest one but the issue is still there. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Change Content-Type to "application/octet-stream" and add Content-Disposition with value "attachment; filename=foo.xlsx" to you respons headers.

Comment: I was having that header but my file name was missing the .xlsx. Any was it is working now thanks.